# Can I accept Input while using the internalConsole in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

New to Python and StackOverflow. Apologies if I miss any formalities.

I am trying to use the `input()` function to accept an input but it doesn't work if my console is set to internalConsole in my `launch.json` file - `"console": "internalConsole"`

[This is the error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtgkB.png)

Is there a way to still accept an input in that case?

It works perfectly fine if the console is set to `integratedTerminal` or `externalTerminal`. But I'd like to be able to accept an input using the `internalConsole`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and typing out the error instead of linking to an image of it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not support it.

internalConsole - VS Code debug console (input stream not supported)

You can find it in the official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging